# Can I specify the collation when performing a SELECT INTO

Tags: t-sql, collation

If I'm selecting from one source into another can I specify the collation at the same time.

e.g.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
INTO DestinationTable
FROM SourceTable
```

Where 'DestinationTable' doesn't already exist.

I know I can do something like

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
INTO DestinationTable
FROM SourceTable
```

In my real problem the data types of the column aren't known in advance so I can't just add the collation to each column. It's in a corner of a legacy application using large nasty stored procedures that generate SQL and I'm trying to get it working on a new server that has a different collation in tempdb with minimal changes.

I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
INTO DestinationTable COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM SourceTable
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you create the table first?

You can define a collation for the relevant columns. On INSERT, they will be coerced.

It sounds like you don't know the structure of the target table though... so then no, you can't without dynamic SQL. Which will make things worse...

Comment: OK - thanks for that, it confirms what I thought. There are hundreds of these SPs and many of them are generating dynamic SQL, so although I could modify things it's route I'm not looking to go down unless I absolutely have no choice - looks like I'll have to see if we can arrange to have the collation changed to match the temp. gak :-(

Comment: How do you set table collation?

Comment: @IanThompson: I was lazy and imprecise. I mean "define collation for the columns first"

Comment: That's OK. I was looking for a quick way to set collation on a table, unfortunately it has to be done for every column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like that if it helps:

```
SELECT *
INTO DestinationTable
FROM
(
SELECT Column1  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, Column2  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM SourceTable
) as t
```

Answer (score 1):

To correct Kasia's answer:

```
SELECT *
INTO DestinationTable
FROM
(
SELECT Column1  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Column1
       ,Column2  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Column1
FROM SourceTable
) as t
```

You have to add an alias for each column to get this work.